# How to solve the error of "SDB_RTN_COORD_ONLY" when connecting MySQL to create table in SequoiaDB?

Tags: mysql, connector, sequoiadb

In the stand-alone mode of SequoiaDB, when I want to connect MySQL to create table, it reported the following error:

```
mysql> use cs;
Database changed
mysql> create table cl(a int, b int, c text, primary key(a, b) ) engine = SequoiaDB ;
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 49841 from storage engine
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `SDB_RTN_COORD_ONLY`  can only be used for coordination node
2. By default, when you create a table on MySQL, it will synchronize to create the corresponding partition table (hash partition, including all partition groups) on SequoiaDB. The partition key takes precedence over the primary key field. If the primary key is not created when creating table, please use the unique key. If the unique key is not created, please use the first field. Users can disable the creation of the default partition table by setting the configuration parameter `sequoiadb_use_partition` to `OFF`. This configuration parameter can also be modified in the shell command line and configuration file.
3. View configuration parameters and shell command:
   mysql> show variables like `sequoiadb%`;
   Turn the `sequoiadb_use_partition` to `ON`

Using command:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sequoiadb_use_partition=OFF;
```

And set it to `OFF`.

For more information, you can refer to [this article](http://doc.sequoiadb.com/cn/SequoiaDB-cat_id-1432190830-edition_id-0)